# how to convert the brackets of a list from [] to()

Tags: python, list

I have a list in this format:

```
a =[["1","2"], ["3","4"]]
```

I need to turn it into this format:

```
a =[("1","2"), ("3","4")]
```

thank you

Comment: They are two different object types.  [lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) are denoted by `[...]` and [tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) are denoted by `(...)`.  It is not that they have different brackets, they are entirely different data structures.  For one thing, tuples are immutable while lists can be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `tuple` and list comprehension :

```
>>> a=[tuple(i) for i in a]
>>> a
[('1', '2'), ('3', '4')]
```

Also you can use `map` function (less performance than list-comprehension):

```
>>> a=map(tuple,a)
>>> a
[('1', '2'), ('3', '4')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, you can use `map`

```
>>> a =[["1","2"], ["3","4"]]
>>> map(tuple, a)
[('1', '2'), ('3', '4')]
```

Comment: You can actually just do: `map(tuple, a)`.